# What happens with saveAll in Parse.com if it fails?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have an array with a lot of PFObjects (up to 720). I do saveAll to save them. What happens though if it fails? will I end up with some objects saved and others not? (bad outcome) or will it be all or none of them saved? (good outcome)

I am getting a fail sometimes, and here's the details.

> Error: Error Domain=com.parse.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected
>   status code in (200-299), got 504" UserInfo=0x2e0d2791
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/multi,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 504}
>   (Code: 100, Version: 1.2.18) 2014-05-22 18:17:10.864 Clan
>   Kingdom[7288:60b] SaveAll error Error Domain=Parse Code=100 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 100.)"
>   UserInfo=0x2e0d2791 {temporary=1, code=100, error=Error
>   Domain=com.parse.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in
>   (200-299), got 504" UserInfo=0x2e0d2791
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/multi,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 504}}

The weird thing is, looking at the dashboard it does seem to have saved the data, so not sure why it gave me that error.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: My code is working fine, but sometimes the network has failed and I can't tell if it's saving none of the data if that happens or not, so wondered if anyone else knew what happens.

Comment: Not sure if this will answer your question per se, but perhaps if there's an error, you could enumerate the objects and their `isDirty` property to see if some saved and others didn't.  I'd personally try again on all objects if there's an error.